# R will plot but won't draw abline

Tags: r, plot

```
> head(returnee)
[1]  1.3936536 -0.6730667  2.3584725  2.3477308  3.2841443  1.3168157
> head(vixee)
[1] 14.75 15.45 17.59 17.74 17.75 18.35
> class(returnee)
[1] "numeric"
> class(vixee)
[1] "numeric"
> plot(returnee, vixee)
> abline(lm(returnee ~ vixee))
```

When I run this, it gives the plot, but there is no abline.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It should be `abline(lm(vixee ~ returnee))` to match the coordinates of the plot.

Answer (score 13):

In contrast to @AK, I was going to say you had your plot backwards.  One or the other ... if the regression is the way you want it (i.e. `y~x`) then try either

```
plot(vixee ~ returnee)  ## formula interface, y~x
```

or

```
plot(returnee,vixee)    ## standard interface, (x,y)
```